# Como fazer o computador escolher entre dois Caracteres

Tags: c#, winforms

Galera, to fazendo um jogo da velha no winforms em C#, porem, estou com um problema, é o seguinte com eu apertar o primeiro botão quero que o computador escolha entre "O" ou "X", já tentei usar a classe random, porem encontrei alguns problemas, pois estou trabalhando com string.

Comment: Coloque o código que você tentou aí na pergunta.

Comment: Joao Victor, por favor maque como resposta para fechar a questão, obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Use o Random, e teste se é par ou ímpar. E atribua um Caractere correspondente, Ex: "X" quando par, e "O" quando ímpar.

Random de 0 a 99, 100 possibilidades, probabilidade iguais.

```
Random r = new Random();
string Jogo =  r.Next(0, 99) % 2 ==0 ? "X" : "O";
```

Certamente que só deve fazer isso na primeira jogada.

Comment: Não seria mais fácil já gerar um número aleatório entre 0 e 1 não?

Comment: poderia sim, foi apenas uma opção minha

Comment: Joao Victor, marque como resposta por favor,  Obrigado.

Comment: @Francisco, a forma que pensou também é valida, você pode por como uma segunda opção pro AP. Ambas resolvem a questão, e o AP ainda fica com 2 exemplos pra escolher a que achar mais adequada. :)